# Understanding the Internal Stack Frames in a Recursive Function Call

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to understand how the system's call stack works internally when a
recursive function is called. Specifically, I'm looking at a function that
computes the maximum depth of a binary tree using a postorder traversal.

I do know there is a stack solution out there, but I would one that mimics the internal call as closely as possible.

Here's the tree I'm working with:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 / \
4   5
```

And here's the recursive function:

```py
def maxDepth(root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
    def dfs_postorder(node: TreeNode) -> Union[int, Literal[0]]:
        if not node:
            return 0

        left_depth = dfs_postorder(node.left)
        right_depth = dfs_postorder(node.right)
        return max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1

    return dfs_postorder(root)
```

When this function is run on the tree, it first calls itself on the root, then
on the root's left child, then on the left child's left child, and so on, until
it reaches a leaf. At each step, it adds a frame to the call stack.

However, I'm confused about when the right children get added to the stack. From
my understanding of the code, it seems like the function would only start
processing the right children after it has finished with all the left children.

For instance, after the first call to the function (with the root node `1`), I
would expect the next call to be with the left child (`2`), and the system's
call stack to look like this:

```py
[(1, "processed"), (2, "process")]
```

where `process` means the node's left and right are yet to be explored and `processed` means
we explored its left and right and probably ready to be "popped" later.

However, I've been told that even at this early stage, the call stack would also
include a frame for the right child (`3`), like this:

```py
[(1, "processed"), (3, "process"), (2, "process")]
```

Why is this the case? How does the system's call stack actually work in this
situation?

---

Stack Solution from Leetcode:

```py
class Solution:
    def maxDepth_stack(self, root: BinaryTreeNode) -> Union[int, Literal[0]]:
        if not root:
            return 0

        stack = [(1, root)] # The stack holds tuples of a node and its depth
        max_depth = 0
        while stack:
            depth, node = stack.pop()
            if node: # If the node is not None
                # Update max_depth if current depth is greater
                max_depth = max(max_depth, depth)
                # Add the left child and its depth to the stack
                stack.append((depth + 1, node.left))
                # Add the right child and its depth to the stack
                stack.append((depth + 1, node.right))
        return max_depth
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've been told that even at this early stage, the call stack would also include a frame for the right child

This is not true. What you described earlier as what you expected, is closer to the truth.

Including the right child on the stack before visiting the left child could be one possible approach if you would implement the algorithm without recursion, using an explicit stack instead. But it is not how the recursive algorithm works.

#### Visualisation

Each execution context of a function creates a stackframe. You could imagine the stack frames as boxes, where each new box is placed on top of a previous box (stacking them). Names like `root` have a scope and lifetime that is limited to the "box" they are defined in.

In the following visualisation, execution goes from top to bottom, and smaller boxes are placed on top of larger boxes, so it is like looking at the stack from "above":

```
┌─maxDepth─────────────────────────────────┐
│ root is TreeNode(1)                      │
│ ┌─dfs_postorder(root)──────────────────┐ │
│ │ node is TreeNode(1)                  │ │
│ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.left)─────────┐ │ │
│ │ │ node is TreeNode(2)              │ │ │
│ │ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.left)─────┐ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ node is TreeNode(4)          │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.left)─┐ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ node is None             │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ return 0                 │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ └──────────────────────────┘ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.right)┐ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ node is None             │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ return 0                 │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ └──────────────────────────┘ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ return max(0, 0) + 1  # 1    │ │ │ │
│ │ │ └──────────────────────────────┘ │ │ │
│ │ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.right)────┐ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ node is TreeNode(5)          │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.left)─┐ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ node is None             │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ return 0                 │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ └──────────────────────────┘ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.right)┐ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ node is None             │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ return 0                 │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ └──────────────────────────┘ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ return max(0, 0) + 1  # 1    │ │ │ │
│ │ │ └──────────────────────────────┘ │ │ │
│ │ │ return max(1, 1) + 1  # 2        │ │ │
│ │ └──────────────────────────────────┘ │ │
│ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.right)────────┐ │ │
│ │ │ node is TreeNode(3)              │ │ │
│ │ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.left)─────┐ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ node is None                 │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ return 0                     │ │ │ │
│ │ │ └──────────────────────────────┘ │ │ │
│ │ │ ┌─dfs_postorder(node.right)────┐ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ node is None                 │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ return 0                     │ │ │ │
│ │ │ └──────────────────────────────┘ │ │ │
│ │ │ return max(0, 0) + 1  # 1        │ │ │
│ │ └──────────────────────────────────┘ │ │
│ │ return max(2, 1) + 1  # 3            │ │
│ └──────────────────────────────────────┘ │
│ return 3                                 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

What is not shown here is the return address, which is also part of a stack frame: when an inner function call returns, the calling function context (preserved in a stack frame) has a trace of where to resume its execution.

When this recursion is "emulated" with an explicit stack and no recursive calls, it is not uncommon to replace this idea of a "return address" with the "next task to do", which is visiting the right child. So that is where the idea comes from to first push the right child (as a deferred task) and then the left child (as the immediate task).

Comment: I think I just want to visualize how the internal call stack works, so with the small example I am thinking how the state of the stack will change after each iteration.

Comment: Added a visualisation.

Comment: First of all, thanks, a brief glance makes it clear and reinforced my intuition. I will reply with a more detailed answer after going through it again.

Btw what tool did you use to draw this diagram?

Comment: I just typed it. I have some keyboard shortcuts to type those box-characters ;-)

Comment: Thanks I have now revisited the official stack solution given and added it to my question as an edit. It adds to my confusion because while I understood how the answer work, I do not get why they add **both nodes** in each iteration, this isn't really exactly how recursive call stack works right?

Comment: They add both nodes in that solution, but notice how the last one is **immediately** popped from the stack as the first action in the next iteration of the loop. This is exactly what I described in the last sentence of my answer. With recursion the execution context is only stacked when making a nested call (but which has its local variables on the stack). The purpose of replacing recursion with an iterative approach is not to **exactly** mimic the callstack, but to somehow make it work elegantly with a stack.

Comment: Thanks, got it! I took the conversion from recursion to stack too rigidly such that I was fixated on a 1-1 solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Good question.

In the recursive solution, when you make a recursive call such as
`maxDepth(node.left)` or `maxDepth(node.right)`, it's like you're saying "pause
the current execution context (the current function call), and start a new
execution context for the called function". This new execution context is placed
on top of the call stack. Once the called function finishes executing and
returns, the paused execution context is resumed, and it's removed from the
stack.

So, for the tree root at node `1`, the `maxDepth` function first calls itself on
the left child (node `2`). This "pauses" the execution context for node `1` and
adds a new execution context for node `2` on the top of the call stack.

The same thing happens again for node `2`, which calls `maxDepth` on its left
child (node `4`), adding a new execution context for node `4` on top of the
stack.

The recursion continues down to the leaf node `4`, at which point `maxDepth(4)`
returns `1` and that execution context is removed from the stack. The execution
context for node `2` is then resumed, and it next calls `maxDepth` on its right
child (node `5`), and so on.

While it's true that the node `3` is added to the call stack only after all the
nodes in the left subtree of `1` have been processed, it's important to remember
that the call stack contains *paused* execution contexts. So even though
`maxDepth(3)` is not called until after `maxDepth(2)`, `maxDepth(1)` (and by
extension, `3`) is still on the call stack during the entire process.

In your stack-based solution, you're trying to simulate this behavior by
manually managing the call stack with your own stack of nodes and actions. When
you add both `(2, "process")` and `(3, "process")` to the stack at the same
time, you're essentially saying "pause the processing of node `1`, and process
nodes `2` and `3`". This is a little different from how the call stack works in
the recursive solution, but it's a necessary adaptation because you're manually
managing the stack of nodes to process.

Answer (score 0):

Calling your tree `node1` and each of its nodes `node2`, `node3` etc., your code proceeds as follows.

We put in **bold** the piece of code on which the execution is currently focused:

```py
maxDepth(node1)
 =~
 { d1 = dfs(node2)
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)     # ^ is a shortcut for MAX
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = dfs(node4)
          d2 = dfs(node5)
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = { d1 = dfs(null)
                 d2 = dfs(null)
                 return (d1^d2+1)
               }
          d2 = dfs(node5)
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = { d1 = { return 0 }
                 d2 = dfs(null)
                 return (d1^d2+1)
               }
          d2 = dfs(node5)
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = { d1 = 0
                 d2 = dfs(null)
                 return (d1^d2+1)
               }
          d2 = dfs(node5)
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = { d1 = 0
                 d2 = { return 0 }
                 return (d1^d2+1)
               }
          d2 = dfs(node5)
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = { d1 = 0
                 d2 = 0
                 return (d1^d2+1)
               }
          d2 = dfs(node5)
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = { return (0+1)
               }
          d2 = dfs(node5)
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = 1
          d2 = dfs(node5)
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = 1
          d2 = { d1 = dfs(null)
                 d2 = dfs(null)
                 return (d1^d2+1)
               }
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = 1
          d2 = { d1 = 0
                 d2 = dfs(null)
                 return (d1^d2+1)
               }
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = 1
          d2 = { d1 = 0
                 d2 = 0
                 return (d1^d2+1)
               }
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = 1
          d2 = { return (0+1)
               }
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { d1 = 1
          d2 = 1
          return (d1^d2+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = { return (1+1)
        }
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = 2
   d2 = dfs(node3)
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { d1 = 2
   d2 = 1
   return (d1^d2+1)
 }
 =~
 { return (2^1+1)
 }
 =~
 3
```

As you can see, each time a piece of code needs to be evaluated (i.e. its value to be found), the corresponding definition's *copy* opens up atop the previous state of affairs, which remains in the background, *"below"* the current execution level, as it were.

If the current top level needs to evaluate some piece of code, same thing happens -- new execution level is opened up with the *copy* of the corresponding definition and all its variables -- thus independent of all the previous variables belonging to the previous *instances* of the definition that was *invoked*.

And when the value is found, the execution layer is no longer needed, having fulfilled its purpose, so is discarded, -- and the value is just used in place of that piece of code.

You can imagine yourself being the computer and the execution layers / invocation copies of procedure definitions / as sheets of paper on which you write the instructions / expressions and their resulting values, disposing of the top-most sheet when it is no longer needed, and continuing with the one below it from *its* current point.

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=paper+stack+user%3A849891).